# Installing Windows 7 on Openstack - Can't find any compatible filesystem drivers or see any disk drives

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, driver, virtualization, openstack

I am attempting to install a windows 7 SP1 32 bit virtual machine instance on my organization's openstack infrastructure. My problem is not related to setting up the .iso on Openstack, it is related to the actual windows 7 installation.

I am at the point where I can create an image with the .iso, click on 'console' and I can access windows 7's GUI as if it was on my own machine. I had no options but to "Install Windows" so I started that, but ran into problems when I get to the screen that says:

> "Where do you want to install windows?"

I cannot see any disk drives to install to. Instead I see:

> No drives were found. Click Load Driver to provide a mass storage
>   driver for installation.

I then click on 'Load Driver' and it tells me:

> To install the device driver needed to access your hard drive, insert the installation media containing the driver files, and click ok. Note: the Installation media can be a floppy disk, CD, DVD, or USB flash drive.

So I click browse and I see these folders:

```
Computer

   CD Drive (D:) GSP 1RMCPRVOL_EN_DVD
      boot
      efi
      sources
      support
      upgrade

   Boot (X:)
      Program Files
      sources
      Users
      Windows
```

From what I can see it looks like an installation CD has been baked into the ISO, but I am stuck on as to how I can use it. Whenever I select any of the folders on the D: drive, I get:

> No device drivers were found. Make sure that the installation mdeia contains the correct drivers, and then click ok.

After some googling I found the location that drivers are stored on windows:

> C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore

which on my system is:

> X:\Windows\System32\DriverStore

And lo and behold there seems to be large list of various ones on my system. They seem to be for everything, mouse, keyboard, speakers, etc. There is about 50-100 of them, all in folders named like

> .inf_x86_neutral_

I tried most of the ones that seemed to be related to the filesystem, ones like

> disk
>
> volume

etc
but none of them seem to be compatible. ("Hide drivers that are not compatible" hides them, and none of them seem to make the file system show up when I try to install them, i just get brought back to an screen with no disk drives found.)

I was just wondering if anyone knows which filesystem drivers I should look for that work for windows 7 on Openstack? Should they be on the prebaked installation CD? If so, where? Is the CD wrong?

Thanks very much.

Comment: I disagree as this is really a question about how virtual drives work on Openstack, and could potentially be quite useful to other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need VirtIO drivers. You will need to attach two devices to your volume, the iso for the OS, and the iso for these drivers.  This should help

http://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/content/windows-image.html

Good luck.

Comment: hi user3357415, thanks very much for your answer :) I actually managed to solve this using that link. I used 'qemu-img create -f qcow2 ws2012.qcow2 15G' and 'virt-install --connect qemu:///system \
  --name ws2012 --ram 2048 --vcpus 2 \
  --network network=default,model=virtio \
  --disk path=ws2012.qcow2,format=qcow2,device=disk,bus=virtio \
  --cdrom /path/to/en_windows_server_2012_x64_dvd.iso \
  --disk path=/path/to/virtio-win-0.1-XX.iso,device=cdrom \
  --vnc --os-type windows --os-variant win2k8'

Comment: substituting my ISO instead of the windows server one and using the virt-io drivers ISO from the fedora projects website (The one linked on the page). I ran through the windows install process on the VM using 'virt-viewer' (This was the result of running the last command, if you have virt-viewer installed it will come up automatically) and then shut the windows VM down and uploaded the resulting qcow2 file to Openstack, which worked :)